# Convert a class to a possible interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection, interface, inversion-of-control

I have two Interfaces in different projects (these projects are not referenced to each other) which have the same methods like this:

In first project we have:

```
public interface IInterfaceA
{
     IAViewModel Do();
}
public interface IAViewModel
{
     int Id { get; set; }
}
public class ServiceA : IInterfaceA
{
     public IBViewModel Do()
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

In second project we have:

```
public interface IInterfaceB
{
    IBViewModel Do();
}
public interface IBViewModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I can create an instance of **ServiceA** at runtime, using some **Reflection**, from second project.

The question is that how can I convert that service to **IInterfaceB**. I mean I want to access it's methods when someone is developing by referring as **IInterfaceB** .

Comment: By "these projects are not referenced to each other" do you mean you are loading the other assembly's types at runtime or something else?

Comment: @SaeedHamed if the type does not implement the interface then you cannot use the interface to call methods on the type.  It does not matter that the type implements another interface with an identical method.

Comment: @phoog: note that in this code example, `ServiceA` does _not_ implement another interface with an identical method. The only `Do()` method shown returns an instance of `IBViewModel`, which prevents it from being an implementation of `IInterfaceA`.

Comment: @jdphenix yes you guessed correctly, I load my assemblies at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your updated question correctly, the fact that `ServiceA` class implements `IInterfaceA` is irrelevant to the question (you don't even know the implemented member).

As far as the question you seem to be asking — is it possible to treat an instance of `ServiceA` as if it were an instance of an implementation of `IInterfaceB` — the answer to that question is "no".

However, you can approximate that result, in one of at least two ways:

1. Use the `dynamic` type. Here, the object won't be visible as `IInterfaceB`, but you can at least call the `Do()` method via a variable typed as `dynamic`.
2. Wrap the instance of `ServiceA` in an adapter class, which does implement `IInterfaceB`, and which delegates its implementation to the instance of `ServiceA`. Then you can use the instance of the wrapper class where you need an object that implements `IInterfaceB`.

For example:

```
class BAdapter : IInterfaceB
{
    private readonly ServiceA _serviceA;

    public BAdapter(ServiceA serviceA)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public IInterfaceB Do() { return _serviceA.Do(); }
}
```

You could alternatively declare `_serviceA` (and the constructor parameter too) in the above example as `dynamic`, and achieve the same result.